# How to create a default empty function in Dart

Tags: function, dart, constructor

I want to pass a callback as a constructor parameter and if the callback is null I want to give a default value. But I don't know a proper way how to generate an empty function in Dart.

[image]

Comment: Please do not use images for presenting code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the callback in parentheses:

```
this.callback = callback ?? (() {})
```

otherwise the braces would be considered as the body of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the arrow function so you have  this.callback = callback ?? () {}

Comment: I already try this one, but it doesn't work